# Color picker for lightning component

Tags: lightning-aura-components, color-picker

The Color Picker is plain as black but I can pick the colour 
[image]

When the input field is clicked black screen appears

`<!-- my static resource -->
<ltng:require scripts="{!$Resource.jsColor + '/jscolor.js'}" />
             <!--Code-->
 <div class="slds-form-element__control"> 
   <input class=" slds-input form-control jscolor" style="{!'background-color:#'+v.mfColor}" id="mfClr" value="{!v.mfColor}" />
 </div>`

which is supposed to be like this

[image]

Answer (score 5, accepted):

[lightning:input](https://developer.salesforce.com/docs/atlas.en-us.lightning.meta/lightning/aura_compref_lightning_input.htm) might be a solution for you if you are in a lightning component:

```
<lightning:input type="color" label="Color" name="color" value="#EEEEEE"/>
```

Comment: really appreciate your help but my requirement is to be in JsColor, so can you help me with that?

Comment: hm nope sorry, might be a good question for [stackoverflow](https://stackoverflow.com/) if it's not related to salesforce.

Answer (score 1):

This is somehow related to LockerService. If you change your API version to 39.0 then it will disable LockerService and work fine.

Comment: yeah so far now took the alternate way and done btw thanks for your update